# Can a bourne shell script close the cmdtool it is running inside?

Tags: sh

I am on a sun ultra10 running solaris.  I'm trying to alter a bourne shell script so that it will close the window (a cmdtool).  Ive tried exit, exit -0, exit -1, system(exit), system("exit").
the script always just exits with the cmdtool still open.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. A workaround would be not to alter the script, but how it is called:

```
./script && exit
```

This will close the shell window after the script has finished execution with return value 0. It may make sense to leave the window open if the script returned with an error, so that any error messages are preserved. If you want the window to close either way, just use a `;` instead of the `&&`.